# WPF Programmatically Right Click within class derived from Button

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, right-click

I have this class:

```
public class LeftClickButton: Button

public LeftClickButton()
{
  this.Click += LeftClickButton_Click;
}
```

I want the LeftClickButton_Click function to raise the right click
event on the LeftClickButton itself, whenever the left button is 
clicked.  I have tried the following with no luck:

```
private void LeftButtonClick_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs = new MouseButtonEventArgs(mouseDevice, 0, MouseButton.Right);
   mouseButtonEventArgs.RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseUpEvent;
   mouseButtonEventArgs.Source = this;
   this.RaiseEvent(mouseButtonEventArgs);
{
```

When left clicked the button calls the function, but nothing ever happens.
Right clicks cause a context menu to appear and all I need is for left clicks
to make the context menu to appear. I think all I really need to know is how
to raise the MouseRightButtonUpEvent within this button.  This has eluded me
for a good two days.  Quite baffling for all the methods I have tried, which 
I will not list here.  The above code looked the most promising.

### Thank you!

Defined in a resource dictionary:

```
<ContextMenu
   x:Key="MyContextMenu"
   Placement="Bottom"
   Style={StaticResource ContextMenuStyle1}">
   <MenuItem
      Command="{Binding Path=SetStuffCommand}"
      Header="Set Stuff"
      Template="{StaticRsource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
</ContextMenu>

<Style x:Key="MyContextMenuButton" TargetType="{x:Type view:LeftClickButton)">
   <Setter Property="ContextMenuService.Placement" Value="Bottom"/>
   <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value"{StaticResource MyContextMenu}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: so a left click just performs a right click, and a right click... is just a right click?

Comment: I'll kill the right click later.  One problem at a time :)  I should mention that I am NOT designing this, I am emulating, so I have no choice in the matter.

Comment: so you just need a left click to open a context menu, which you have already defined? can you post some code to show your context menu?

Comment: I'll see what I can do, but I'm 99% sure that is not going to help you at all, because it is defined in styles, controltemplates and datatemplates and put inside of a contentcontrol INSIDE of a cell in a datagrid.  I would have to post pages and pages to show the full scope  of this screen.

Comment: ok don't mind then, as you said it wouldn't help as much

Comment: Show the context on the left click.  Don't worry about triggering the right click.

Comment: "Show the context on the left click. Don't worry about triggering the right click" -- Michael Puckett.  How?  Looking at the way that the context menu is added to the custom button via a style, how do I accomplish this?  Will I need to write a fully custom user control?  Also, this doesn't answer my question, which is How do I invoke a right click programmatically from inside the custom control.  This should NOT be a complicated thing to do, after all, I am already inside of the class itself.  Why isn't it working?

Comment: I found a solution, myself.  (A week later).  I will post it tomorrow.  No time left today.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is the crucial code for what I ended up doing.  Mind you, I did not ever really figure out how to get the same response, through code, out of a button as if I had right clicked it, but I did get my context menu to launch and in the right place.  I actually changed the class to one derived from TextBlock as opposed to Button, and used the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp to take the place of the Click method:

```
public class LeftClickTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public LeftClickTextBlock()
    {
       this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += this.LeftClickTextBlock_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
    } 

    private void LeftClickTextBlock_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       LeftClickTextBlock lcb = sender as LeftClickTextBlock;
       ContextMenu contextMenu = lcb.ContextMenu;
       contextMenu.PlacementTarget = lcb;
       contextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
       contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

And then, of course, this needed slightly adjusted styles:

```
<Style x:Key="MyContextMenuTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type view:LeftClickTextBlock)">
   <Setter Property="ContextMenuService.Placement" Value="Bottom"/>
   <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value"{StaticResource MyContextMenu}"/>
</Style>
```

This was ultimately placed within a data template that allows me to control 
not only the type of context menu that appears when the an individual data grid
element is clicked, but also what view model level object the context menu's 
menu items are bound to.  I won't post all the code here, but I'm thinking
about posting it somewhere, because it really gives full view model control
over every cell and binding in the data grid.

Again, defined in a ResourceDictionary or in the App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type viewModel:DataItem}>
   <view:LeftClickTextBlock
      Background="Transparent"
      Style="{StaticResource MyContextMenuTextBlock}"
      Text="{Binding Path=DataString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```